# Best way to show an Instagram post in iOS?

Tags: ios, instagram

Simple question, how to embed an Instagram post like below in a native iOS / Swift app?

[image: Random Instagram post]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not really very simple. The Instagram API is quite restrictive (see [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)). The only way you'll really be able to do it is with a `WKWebView` showing the web page.

Alternatively if you specifically just want the image without the comments and surrounding bits, fetch the web page and scrape it. The question doesn't make it clear exactly what from the instagram post is being sought.